# I have installed sdk and have set its environment but its shows this and creating the gradle error

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, sdk

```
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
  CPU: "(16) x64 AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics         "
  Memory: 5.13 GB / 15.42 GB
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 16.16.0
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 8.11.0
    path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Watchman: Not Found
SDKs:
  Android SDK: Not Found
  Windows SDK:
    AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
IDEs:
  Android Studio: AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996
  Visual Studio: Not Found
Languages:
  Java: 11.0.20
  Ruby: Not Found
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.4
    wanted: 0.72.4
  react-native-windows: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: Not found
  newArchEnabled: Not found
```

???????????????????????????????????????

AND THIS ERROR

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

i TRIED ALL NOTHING HAPPENED